# Catch-all route for production build of Vue Router/Vite-based SPA

Tags: vue-router, vite

I have a Vue3-based SPA using Vue Router and Vite as dev server. The app has three valid URL paths:

1. /
2. /first
3. /second

For production, it will be deployed on Apache under a prefix, i.e. the production URL paths will be:

1. /prefix
2. /prefix/first
3. /prefix/second

What I want to achieve is that clients should be redirected to a valid URL path (e.g. /prefix) of the application **even when they initially request an invalid URL path**, such as /prefix/invalid.

For this purpose, I've defined the following router.js:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/first",
    component: () => import("./components/First.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/second",
    component: () => import("./components/Second.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/:anything+",
    redirect: "/"
  },
];
const router = createRouter({history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL), routes});
export default router;
```

The third route entry defines a [catch-all route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route) that will match whenever clients request an invalid URL path. This works fine in development on Vite, i.e. when serving the app via `npm run dev -- --base='/prefix/'`. Even when the browser **initially** requests /prefix/invalid, the app's /prefix route is loaded and displayed.

When deploying with `npm run build -- --base='/prefix/'` for production, however, the catch-all route starts working only after clients have initially requested /prefix or /prefix/index.html and the SPA has been loaded. When they initially request /prefix/invalid or even /prefix/first or /prefix/second, Apache responds with **404 Not Found**. This is of course because the whole routing is implemented client-side in JavaScript, so my catch-all route and everything else routing-related will only work once the SPA itself has been loaded and its JavaScript is executing in the browser.

**My question is:** is there a way to make initial requests for invalid URL paths work in production on Apache like in dev on Vite? I tried adding a file public/.htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 import.meta.env.BASE_URL
```

But the expression `import.meta.env.BASE_URL`, which Vite statically replaces with the [`base` config option value](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) in router.js, is not replaced in this file - which is consistent with the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory) of the public directory. Hence this approach doesn't work.

Not sure whether I'm following the right path with .htaccess or whether my business problem has any better -possibly simpler- solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by generating .htaccess dynamically using a simple Vite plugin, which I define inline in vite.config.js for simplicity.

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// A private Vite plugin for generating .htaccess dynamically
function generateHtaccess () {

  // Resolved Vite configuration, including "base" option
  let viteConfig;

  return {
    name: 'generate-htaccess',

    // Rollup Plugin API output generation hook
    // See https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#generatebundle
    generateBundle() {
      this.emitFile({
        type: 'asset',
        fileName: '.htaccess',
        source: `ErrorDocument 404 ${viteConfig.base}\n`
      });
    },

    // Vite Plugin API specific hook
    // See https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configresolved
    configResolved(resolvedConfig) {
      viteConfig = resolvedConfig;
    },
  };
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), generateHtaccess()],
});
```

A non-prefixed production build, such as `npx vite build`, will hence generate `dist/.htaccess` with the following content:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

while specifying a prefix, e.g. `npx vite build --base='/~user/'` will generate:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /~user/
```

With this .htaccess, clients initially requesting any invalid URL path in production on Apache will be properly redirected to the same catch-all route -the app's root directory- as defined in router.js. This behavior will work consistently for any `--base` value supplied at build time.